# Low-Speed CANbus Common-Mode Choke Insertion Loss

Tags: noise, ltspice, can, modeling, common-mode-choke

I'm designing a low-speed CAN transceiver breakout-board (schematic below) and I'm trying to select the proper choke to use to reduce common-mode noise. I've found a few common-mode chokes meant specifically for CAN, and the one I'm trying to model is DLW43MH201XK2L. It has a DCR of 4.5Ohms and an LCM of 200uH. My issue is that I'm not quite sure how to model the circuit to determine the insertion loss.[image]

I know that \$ I_{L}= 20log\left ( \frac{V2}{V1} \right )\$.
I'm thinking the circuit looks something like below, but again, I'm not sure if this is correct so not sure if my insertion-loss figures given in the AC simulation are correct. It would also be nice to figure out how to model the circuit to determine the differential-mode insertion loss to ascertain the distortion caused to the signal, but I'm not sure how to do that either, and Ldiff isn't given in the datasheet. Is my model correct?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn't fault tolerant CAN always 5V? The TJA1055T spec says Vcc = 5V so why are you using 3.3V?

Comment: That inductor is pretty poor on details in the data sheet so unless you are stuck on using it, go hunt down a device that has more support.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah I took this design from someone else and haven't had the chance to do a full design review, but that's definitely a mistake so thank you.